# I am making a phonegap app, iframes open in safari automatically - how can I stop this?

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova

Hi the question more or less sums it up.
I've been around the internet now though and can't find anything that will fix my problem.
It's worth noting that I've been here
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-iphone/issues/76

and tried the plist option but no luck.

I've also made it so external links when clicked on open in a new window using this.
http://solutions.michaelbrooks.ca/2011/02/15/open-external-links-in-safariapp/

But I'm at a loss at how to accomplish what I want.
I'm aware that what I'm trying to do is 'wrong' in apples eye but can't figure out a way of doing it better. The content in the iframe is a youtube video. Is there a better way of displaying them?

Thanks for your help.
Richard

Comment: What about the old embedding code using `<object>`is this an option for you? If the plist-trick doesn't work for you, why you don't ask the devs of PhoneGap why it doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with phonegap 1.1 (see http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:pxZoAitrtjMJ:https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-iphone/issues/296+Fixed+%23296+iFrames+open+in+Mobile+Safari&cd=1&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=de)

But phonegap 1.2 was just released fixing that issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help I've upgraded and understand I need to add some settings in the plist document but I still can't get it to work.
It's a video iframe for youtube could you tell me what settings I need.
ta
Richard